# IBM Worklight 6.1 wlCommonInit() behaviour

Tags: initialization, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to know what is exactly the behaviour of `wlCommonInit()` function.

I have moved my initialization code into this function, but then it seems to be not called in the case of connection to the server failure.

- is `wlCommonInit()` called when the Worklight server is not reachable ?
- If I want to use direct update, I want to call `WL.Client.updateUserInfo()` on my initialization, and I want the app to be working also in offline mode, does this mean I must implement `onConnectionFailure` in `wlInitOptions` ?
- If I implement `onConnectionFailure` in `wlInitOptions`, can I display the default popup that inform about the connection failure, and provide details ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on the logic you wrote in your "initialization code" IMO. The question is somewhat cryptic...

1. The `wlCommonInit` function is called once the Worklight framework has completed initialization. If you set `connectOnStartup` to `true`, only if connection to the server is successful, it will then be called.
2. Direct Update is not related to any specific API you implement in your application. If you change any web resource in your project (HTML, CSS, JavaScript, images, ...), this will trigger a Direct Update in the application.

   A Direct Update is checked in 2 scenarios:

   - on application launch, and
   - on return to the foreground (if the app was in the background)

   The Direct Update check is performed **only** if and when the application connects to the Worklight Server. If you did not previously set your application by either using `connectOnStartup:true` or used `WL.Client.connect` or invoked an adapter procedure (all three send a request to the server), the Direct Update check will not be done.
3. If you choose to override the default dialog provided by Worklight by using `onConnectionFailure`, the Details button (which I assume if what you wanted) - is not available. By overriding, you select to fully customize it.

Comment: for point 1/, I am testing on iOS simulator, and I have put my initialization inside a function and called it inside wlCommonInit, but when I disconnect my computer and try again, I see that I have the error popup (with details button), but the initialization don't take place !

Comment: You are asking too vague questions. Produce a sample project and provide it in your question.

Comment: You can just add alert("Hello") inside wlCommonInit() function, and test it online and offline. It is not fired when you are offline!

Comment: What do you mean by "offline"? A blank new project that the only change in it is alert("hello") in wlcommoninit?

Comment: by offline, I mean if you test the application when you have no internet connection!  Yes for the blank project with just alert("Hello") in wlcommoninit

Comment: I was confused. I double-checked now. In case of connectOnStartup:true, if the app failed connecting to the server, wlCommonInit will not take please because the initialization did not successfully complete. I updated my answer accordingly.